# Subclass of UIImageView not responding to touch event?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a class Player that is a subclass of UIImageView. They are spawned by another class and remain on the screen for 3 seconds before disappearing. If the user clicks the image though, it should disappear immediately. Unfortunately `touchesBegan` is never firing. I do have userInteractionEnabled set to YES.

```
-(id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    self = [super initWithImage:image];

    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

        // start timers to have it disappear after 3 sec
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    // never called
    [self disappear:nil];
}
```

All of the answers I can find say to set userInteractionEnabled to YES, but I have that done already. If it means anything, the images are being produced by another class called Manager, which it's own UIImageView as the background of the app. These images are smaller and are being periodically flashed on top of that background. The background UIImageView also has userInteractionEnabled set to YES. The images flash okay, they just don't respond to the touch event.

The Player class is made from the Manager class like this:

```
Player* t = [[Player alloc] initWithImage:[imgArray objectAtIndex:imageIndex]];
[field addSubview:t];
[t becomeFirstResponder];
```

`field` is the background image (also a UIImageView).

Comment: This is obviously not your actual code as you are not returning self on your initialisation method?

Comment: You haven't return self in your init metod or just forgot write it here?

Comment: That is correct I truncated the init method before making the timer etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed that the field UIImageView needed userInteractionEnabled set to YES. I realized this before but had been setting it in the init method. When I moved it to awakeFromNib, everything worked :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: non-UIGestureRecognizer version:

```
-(id)initWithImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    if (( self = [ super initWithImage:image ] ))
    {
        UIControl * control = [ [ [ UIControl alloc ] initWithFrame:self.bounds ] autorelease ] ; 
        [ button addTarget:self action:@selector( wasTapped ) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside ] ;

        [ self addSubview:control ];
    }
}
```

You might try with a UIGestureRecognizer instead... i.e.

```
-(id)initWithImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    if (( self = [ super initWithImage:image ] ))
    {
        ...
        UIGestureRecognizer * recognizer = [ [ [ UITapGestureRecognizer alloc ] initWithTarget:self action:@selector( myTapHandler: ) ] autorelease ] ;
        [ self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer ] ;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a bug in a programming assignment and we have not gotten to UIGestureRecognizer yet, thanks though :)

Comment: What happens if you call `-becomeFirstResponder` on your view first?

Comment: I edited the OP with where I put it... doesn't seem to make a difference. Is that where I should should call it?

Comment: I think a better solution is to add a UIButton to your UIImageView instead... I'll add another answer

Comment: I added a version using UIControl--now your image view doesn't have to be first responder